# How to add a callback and a function at the same time in a single onClick in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a button that has a callback function in which I want to add another function that plays music. How do I do this?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Howl } from 'howler';

const StartButton = ({ callback }) => {
    function sound() {
        const sound = new Howl( {
            src: [ 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3'],
            html5: true,
        });

    }
    return (
        <div className='button' onClick={()=>{ sound(); callback}}>Start Game</div>
    );
}

export default StartButton;
```

I have an error after running the code above: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: In JavaScript, any variable can be called as a function by simply adding `()` at the end. Whether or not it actually executes will depend on the value of the variable. So that means, in the `onClick`, we could do: `onClick={() => { sound(); callback() }}`

Comment: By definition, a callback ***is*** a function. So you're asking how to call two functions on one click. Any function can call an infinite number of other functions. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot to invoke the function itself**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Howl } from 'howler';

const StartButton = ({ callback }) => {
  function sound() {
    const sound = new Howl({
      src: [ 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3' ],
      html5: true
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="button"
        onClick={ () => {
          sound();
          callback(); // <== HERE
        } }>
      Start Game
    </div>
  );
};

export default StartButton;
```

---

I would suggest that you put that inside the `sound` function and not to create another function in the onClick event, it could be cleaner

```
import React from 'react';
import { Howl } from 'howler';

const StartButton = ({ callback }) => {
  function sound() {
    const sound = new Howl({
      src: [ 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3' ],
      html5: true
    });

    callback();
  }

  return (
    <div className="button" onClick={ sound }>
      Start Game
    </div>
  );
};

export default StartButton;
```

Comment: By inserting `callback()` inside `sound()` you make it impossible for `sound()` to be called without performing `callback()`. It's cleaner to call them separately from the `onClick()` in case any of them needs to be executed without the other, now or at some future point.

Comment: I'd agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

l get you but onClick is not support this arguments.
you can code like this

```
onClick={() => { sound()}}

function sound() {
  ...
  callback() 
}
function callback() {
  ...
}
```